# Coloring buttons css

Tags: html, css

I have a list that has 4 buttons, each button is of the same class and each button has its own id. I want the 4 buttons to be the same shape and size but different colors. (The letters C R U D will be replaced later with something more appropriate)

--html snippet

```
<ul id="query_type">
  <li class="round-button" id="create">C</li>
  <li class="round-button" id="read">R</li>
  <li class="round-button" id="update">U</li>
  <li class="round-button" id="delete">D</li>
</ul>
```

-css file

```
.round-button {
    width: 10%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #464646;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}

.round-button:hover {
    background: #262626;
}
```

How do i override the background property of .round-button for each id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ids are more specific than classes so you could target them only with id.

```css
.round-button {
  width: 10%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #464646;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button:hover {
  background: #262626;
}
#create {
  background: orange;
}
#read {
  background: yellow;
}
#update {
  background: blue;
}
#delete {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul id="query_type">
  <li class="round-button" id="create">C</li>
  <li class="round-button" id="read">R</li>
  <li class="round-button" id="update">U</li>
  <li class="round-button" id="delete">D</li>
</ul>
```

Reference: [Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a different class for each button that you want with a different color, example:

```
<ul id="query_type">
  <li class="round-button yellow" id="create">C</li>
  <li class="round-button red" id="read">R</li>
  <li class="round-button green" id="update">U</li>
  <li class="round-button pink" id="delete">D</li>
</ul>
```

and in the css create the respective background color for each class.

or you can use their ID's to reference each button and assign it a background color:

```
#create {
    background: blue;
}
#delete {
    background: red;
}
```

or even use other selector like:

```
#query_type li:nth-child(1) { background: .... }
#query_type li:nth-child(2) { background: .... }
#query_type li:nth-child(3) { background: .... }
#query_type li:nth-child(4) { background: .... }
```

Its just a matter of choosing the selector you want.